# Why the Torah is not read in public every day?

Tags: halacha-theory, torah-reading, moshe-rabbeinu

Following [my previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101872/what-does-it-mean-stop-reading-torah-4-times-a-week-bk-82a), the Prophets (Moses) commanded the Jewish nation to read the Torah in public three days a week ([B"K 82a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Kamma.82a.6?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> עמדו נביאים שביניהם ותיקנו להם שיהו קורין בשבת ומפסיקין באחד בשבת וקורין בשני ומפסיקין שלישי ורביעי וקורין בחמישי ומפסיקין ערב שבת כדי שלא ילינו ג’ ימים בלא תורה
>
> The prophets among them thereupon rose and enacted that they should publicly read the law on Sabbath, make a break on Sunday, read again on Monday, make a break again on Tuesday and Wednesday, read again on Thursday and then make a break on Friday so that they should not be kept for three days without Torah.’

Why reading Torah is not a part of everyday service? I could think of a lot of reasons why it really should.

Comment: .......such as?

Comment: @robev לֹא-יָמוּשׁ סֵפֶר הַתּוֹרָה הַזֶּה מִפִּיךָ, וְהָגִיתָ בּוֹ יוֹמָם וָלַיְלָה? מחדש בטובו בכל יום וכו'?

Comment: What do any of those verses have to do with public recitation of the Torah? The Torah doesn't even discuss public recitations, other than Hakhel

Comment: טרחא דצבורא....

Comment: @robev Sometimes we're so used to a fixed pattern, we can't think of anything else, but for me, it seems far more reasonable to read the Torah every day, even a small portion, as every day is a new day. Alternatively, maybe the portions of the Torah in the Teffilah would suffice, so we won't need reading Torah in public at all?

Comment: Similarly why not have a Pesach Seder every night?

Comment: Doing a Passover Seder (or any other holiday observance) on the wrong day would run afoul of Bal Tosif, wouldn't it? In contrast, we have Birkat haTorah everyday, so why not have a public reading as well as private study?